# Is there way to convert float from 32bit integer?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, integer

using c#

the float value i need to read

```
= 24.500000
```

when i try to read i get this result

```
= 1103364096
```

what conversion should i do to get the real value? i need help on this.

my failed attempts:

```
int data_1 = 1103364096;
UInt16 value = (UInt16)x;
```

```
ushort data_2= (ushort)(1103364096 & ((1 << 16) - 1));
```

```
int r = 1103364096;
short trimmed = unchecked((short)r);
```

these don't work!

Comment: Are you looking for `BitConverter`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.tosingle?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Jeremy, you need to use `BitConverter`.
We'll first get the byte representation of the integer `i`, then interpret those bytes as a `float`:

```cs
int i = 1103364096;
byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
float f = BitConverter.ToSingle(b, 0);
Console.WriteLine(f); // outputs 24.5
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/BEPAU17359)

Comment: So how can I do the opposite?
float i = 24.5;
byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);?
float f = BitConverter.ToSingle(b, 0); ?
Console.WriteLine(f); // outputs 1103364096   how do i do this

Comment: @Adem `.GetBytes` has a `float` overload, so you can use `byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(123.45f);` and then you can use `int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 0);`

Comment: string data = "123.45"
byte[] b =BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToDouble(data)f); == error
how will the string data enter that pattern "123.45"f is wrong

Comment: A float is a single, not a double. It seems that what you're asking now is outside the scope of this question, so I suggest asking a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Convert.ToFloat(x)` to convert (from anything) to a float.
Use `Convert.ToInt32(x)` to convert (from anything) to an Int32.

Comment: And how does that turn `1103364096` into `24.5`?